# column of data to be separated into a rows based on a common value and its subsequent data

Tags: bash, validation, text, output, row

i have a column of data in a test1.txt file that looks like this:

sys@hostname:/tmp/  cat -n  test1.txt

1 row1.txt

2 1234

3 2331

4 2238

5 row2.txt

6 2773

7 6673

I would like to have this data converted into two rows based on a common value , maybe *.txt.  Maybe leverage grep , awk or sed for this if possible.

The data of test1.text will change adding more data so grep -A3/B3 or grep -A2/B2 will not work as the values will change and the command will be automated.

The end result will should display :

sys@hostname:/tmp/ cat -n text2.txt

1 row1.txt,1234,2331,2238

2 row2.txt,2773,6673

i tried a number of variations leveraging a for loop but could not manage to get it to work.

Comment: i think i answered my own question on this: 

cat test1.txt | tr '\n' ',' | grep -o col_,,,[^.col]* > cat2.txt

Comment: If you start by writing the code logic in pseudo-code, fine-grained for each task that you are trying to accomplish, in the correct sequence and in the correct context, then having that worded so that it does exactly what you want it to do will, almost explicitly, tell you WHAT you need to code for each of those, not the HOW. The HOW is the nitty gritty of coding. Saying that you answered your own question suggest that you were almost there, at first, but not quite. If you give that a try, the solution will almost pop out of the page at you.

Comment: You almost have it in your comment.  You need to add the pipe segment  | sed '+s\,row+\nrow+g' .

Answer (score 0):

If you want an **[awk](/questions/tagged/awk)** solution, here it is:

```
#!/bin/bash

cat >test1.txt <<"EnDoFiNpUt"
row1.txt
1234
2331
2238
row2.txt
2773
6673
EnDoFiNpUt


awk 'BEGIN{ first=1 ; }{
    if( $0 != "" ){
        if( $1 ~ /^row/ ){
            if( first == 1 ){
                printf("%s", $0 ) ;
            }else{
                printf("\n%s", $0 ) ;
            } ;
            first=0 ;
        }else{
            printf(",%s", $0 );
        } ;
    } ;
}END{
    print "" ;
}' test1.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

For **[sed](/questions/tagged/sed)**-based solution, you have to get rid of the stray "," from the end of the last line:

```
cat test1.txt | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's+,$++' | sed 's+\,row+\nrow+g'
```